how to create android layout like image?
android layout

I am new in Android. I am doing android application. I have tried many options. but layout didn't match like this.
I am trying so much but not get exactly solution.
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/card_excel2pdf"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"

            android:padding="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_start" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:background="@drawable/bottom_background"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                android:textSize="16sp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


Not sure your question. What are you trying to achieve?
